# Stop Excel users from closing a spreadsheet using the X, Minimize and Maximize buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with stopping a spreadsheet in Excel from closing if the cell H40 doesn't contain a text value.

Here is a macro for a range, not individual cells:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sheets("Daily Centre Inputs").Range("D6,F6,C8:C18,I6:I18,A22:K22,A29,A36,H36").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Incomplete fields. Please check your data ensuring any required cells are complete otherwise you will not be able to close or save the workbook"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In general users should be able to close a spreadsheet regardless of any validation rules - how much would you want it to disregard the wishes of the owner of the computer? If someone were to send such a file to you, would you want it to take over your computer until you had satisfied some data entry rules, even if you did not want to complete those fields?

Comment: Even if this is possible, users could use "force close" features to kill the Excel task instead of filling in the data.

Comment: Sorry, I am doing tests on this specific spreadhsheet, and want to prevent someone from closing it until the final cell is completed

Comment: it is possible, I have already found macros for this, but none for an individual cell, all I found are for ranges

Comment: You may want to create an confirmation msgbox over restricting their ability to close the program.

Comment: Please add to the question what you have found for ranges - that might be something that can be applied to cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will trigger whenever H40 is changed and is empty. You will want to add it to the VBA Sheet that you want it to trigger on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H40")) Is Nothing Then
        If IsEmpty(Range("H40")) Then
            ' do something
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```